# Elminating duplicate selection in two fields in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a table and I am doing inner join with the same table. Here is the table structure

```
Acct#|Name |Med_Rec|Admit Date
-----|-----|-------|----------
   1 |MIKE |100    |7/1/2017
   2 |MIKE |100    |7/2/2017
   3 |MIKE |100    |7/3/2017
   4 |CHRIS|101    |5/5/2017
   5 |CHRIS|101    |5/7/2017
```

My goal is to get accounts with admit date within 3 consecutive days(i.e. Mike was admitted first on 7/1/2017 then next day was admitted again and the day after too). My goal result should be like this

```
Acct|Name |Admit_Date|Othr_Acct|Admit_Date
----|-----|----------|---------|-----------
   1|MIKE |7/1/2017  |    2    |7/2/2017
   1|MIKE |7/1/2017  |    3    |7/3/2017
   4|CHRIS|5/5/2017  |    5    |5/7/2017
```

The issue I am facing is that I am getting my query results where Acct number is selected again. It should not appear again as I already listed it under "Othr_Acct"

```
Acct|Name |Admit_Date|Othr_Acct|Admit_Date
----|-----|----------|---------|-----------
   1|MIKE |7/1/2017  |    2    |7/2/2017
   1|MIKE |7/1/2017  |    3    |7/3/2017
   2|MIKE |7/2/2017  |    3    |7/3/2017<-wrong it was already selected
   4|CHRIS|5/5/2017  |    5    |5/7/2017


SELECT 
A.Acct
A.Name 
A.Admit_Date
B.Acct AS Othr_Acct
B.Admit_Date

FROM 
A.TABLE
B.TABLE

WHERE 

A.Med_Rec=B.Med_Rec
AND B.Admit_Date-A.Admit_Date BETWEEN 0 AND 2
AND A.Acct<>B.Acct
```

Answer (score 0):

Join table B only to the first row from table A.
Use a subquery and `row_number` function to number rows in A

```
SELECT 
    A.Acct,
    A.Name ,
    A.Admit_Date,
    B.Acct AS Othr_Acct,
    B.Admit_Date
FROM (
   SELECT t.*, 
    row_number() over (partition by Med_Rec order by Admit_Date) As rn
   FROM TABLE1 t
) a
JOIN TABLE1 b
ON A.rn = 1 AND A.Med_Rec=B.Med_Rec
AND B.Admit_Date-A.Admit_Date BETWEEN 0 AND 2
AND A.Acct<>B.Acct
```